# powershell browser access on WSL2

Tags: azure, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm trying to run `Connect-AzAccount` in WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 but hit the following

```
Connect-AzAccount
WARNING: Unable to acquire token for tenant 'organizations'
WARNING: Interactive authentication is not supported in this session, please run Connect-AzAccount using switch -DeviceCode.
```

Is there a way to tell powershell where Browser is?
For instance, `export BROWSER="wslview"` works for bash

Comment: I think it's fine to use `-DeviceCode` option it works fine.

Comment: As of July 2023, WSL 2 has added the ability to run Linux GUI apps.  You can now install a web browser in WSL and it will launch when running Connect-AzAccount (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps#install-google-chrome-for-linux )

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a way to tell it where Browser is, my workaround is to use a non-interactive way to login directly.

1.[Register an application with Azure AD and create a service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#register-an-application-with-azure-ad-and-create-a-service-principal).

2.[Get values for signing in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#get-tenant-and-app-id-values-for-signing-in) and [create a new application secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#option-2-create-a-new-application-secret).

3.Then use the commands below to login.

```
$azureAplicationId ="<application-id>"
$azureTenantId= "<tenant-id>"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "<application-secret>" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId , $azurePassword)
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $azureTenantId -ServicePrincipal
```

If your purpose is to use the powershell to access azure resources, don't forget to [assign an RBAC role to the service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal) at the scope you want e.g. subscription, resource group, etc.